# Using SquishIt to combine js files has no effect?

Tags: squishit

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
  SquishIt.JavaScript.Add(
    Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery_ui.js"),
    Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery_1.4.4.js")
  );
}
@SquishIt.JavaScript.Render(Url.Content("~/Scripts/min.js"))
```

It shows like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery_ui.js"></script>`
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery_1.4.4.js"></script>`
```

Where is "min.js"?

The two js files are not combine into one js named min.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

To help with debugging, SquishIt does not do anything to the files when in debug mode.

However, you can add a `.ForceRelease()` call before the `.Render(...)` call to force it to combine the files as if it's in release mode:

```
@SquishIt.JavaScript.ForceRelease().Render(Url.Content("~/Scripts/min.js"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you have debug="true" in web.config?  It must be set to "false" for squishit to work:  http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher